# Minimal polynomial and possible Jordan forms

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

> Let $A$ be an $8\times 8$ complex matrix with characteristic polynomial $$p_A(x)=(x-1)^4(x+2)^2(x^2+1)$$ and minimal polynomial $$m_A(x)=(x-1)^2(x+2)^2(x^2+1).$$ Determine all possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$. Also, what is the dimension of the eigenspace for $\lambda = 1$ for each case?

I haven't learned minimal polynomial yet, so I wanted to check if I am on the right track.

From the characteristic polynomial, the eigenvalues are $i,-i,-2,1$. From the minimal polynomial, the block sizes are $1,1,2$ for eigenvalues $i,-i,-2$ respectively. For $\lambda = 1$, the largest block size is 2, so the possible block sizes are $2,2$, which has eigenspace dim of 2 ($J_1$). Or the sizes are $2,1,1$, which has eigenspace dim of 3 ($J_2$). Writing the full Jordan matrix:

$J_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&-2&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&-2&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&i&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-i\end{pmatrix}$, $J_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&-2&1&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&-2&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&i&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&-i\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Looks to me like you did everything right!

Comment: @Christian yay! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You identified the blocks and eigenspace dimensions correctly. The blocks for a given form, however, can be permuted.  Thus, your first matrix represents 5!/2! = 60 forms, and your second matrix, 6!/2! = 360 forms for a total of 420 forms.